# How to change permissions/policies of another admin-account.?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator, group-policy

On my Windows7 PC i have now 2 admin-accounts. The problem is that one of them does not have any rights/permissions anymore to startup any program (after some virus attack which also changed the UAC). Therefore I have created an additional admin-account which has all the rights/permissions on the PC. On that account I also adjusted the UAC again. In the user overview I see that both are administrator, but the first account doesn't have any access-permissions anymore..
How to adjust those rights/permissions of the first admin-account?.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it depends on the error you're receiving. If it's on the particular executable you'll have to allow permissions on that particular file. It can also be a policy depending on your OS (Ctrl+R > secpol.msc, read the Explain tab for the default). It can also have damaged your machine on a relatively low level. That's probably the least of your worries though. You won't want to do this. You'll want to boot into safe mode, install an antivirus to remove the malware, and potentially reinstall windows on your machine if you can afford the time. A virus attack isn't something you just kinda "work around".